# Proving $E[xx'\otimes xx'] \succ E[xx']\otimes E[xx']$

Tags: moments

I suspect the following relation is true for random variable in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can someone suggest a way of proving it?

$$E[xx'\otimes xx'] \succ E[xx']\otimes E[xx']$$

Using [Loewner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order) symbol $\succ$ and Kronecker product symbol $\otimes$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite  $xx'$ as a $d^2$-vector $y$. The elements of $(xx') \otimes (xx')$ are the elements of $yy'$, with the same permutation $P$ applied to rows and columns.

Let $a$ be a unit $d^2$-vector. Then as scalars
$$E[a'yy'a]\geq a'E[y]E[y]'a$$
regardless of $a$, and so $$E[yy']\succ E[y]E[y]'$$
in the Loewner order.
Call  the permutation $P$. We have
$$E[P(xx') \otimes (xx')P']\succ PE[(xx')] \otimes E(xx')P']$$
and the permutation doesn't affect the Loewner ordering.

Comment: I'm confused about dimensions, xx'a is a vector, so how did you get from comparing scalars to comparing vectors?

Comment: Ok, I was confused by your notation. The idea still holds, that the easiest way to do this is to show the inequality holds for all 1-d projections.

Comment: Got it. Actually, no permutation is even needed here since (xx')\otimes(xx')=yy' where  y=vec(xx')

Comment: I guess it's even stronger than Loewner ordering -- every element of left matrix is larger than right, which implies Loewner

Comment: I didn't want to go find a pen and paper to work out what the ordering would be, so I just put in a permutation in case ;-)

Comment: Actually how do you show that E[yy']>E[y]E[y]'? This is true for diagonal entries by Jensen's, but for non-diagonal, this is equivalent to claim that E[y_1 y_2]>E[y_1]E[y_2]

Comment: The LHS minus the RHS is a covariance matrix.